# How to make StaleElementReferenceException catcher in a Try loop?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am using this function to battle random StaleElementReferenceException, but it fails to do so. If I don't get the StaleElementReferenceException, the test is running and passing perfectly.

```
sleep_pause = 1
find_element_retries = 3
find_element_wait_timeout = 5

def find_element_with_retry(driver, by, value):
    print("Function called")
    for _ in range(find_element_retries):
        try:
            print("Wait triggered")
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, cfg.find_element_wait_timeout).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((by, value)))
            print(f"Element text:{element.text}")
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            # If a StaleElementReferenceException occurs, retry after a short delay
            print(f"Stale element occured. Retrying after {find_element_wait_timeout} seconds for {find_element_retries} times")
            time.sleep(sleep_pause)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An exception occurred: {str(e)}")
        else:
            # If the element is found successfully, return it
            return element
```

I then call this function from the Page Objects in next way:

```
    def press_button(self):
        button = find_element_with_retry(self.driver, By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".button-icon")
        button.click()
```

I have tried adding multiple print elements to know at what point it fails and example output is:

```
FAILED             [ 11%]
Function called
Wait triggered
Element text: Button
```

and this stacktrace:

```
E       selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: stale element not found
E         (Session info: chrome=116.0.5845.140); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#stale-element-reference-exception
E       Stacktrace:
E       0   chromedriver                        0x000000010083a65c chromedriver + 4318812
E       1   chromedriver                        0x0000000100832d00 chromedriver + 4287744
E       2   chromedriver                        0x00000001004647ec chromedriver + 296940
E       3   chromedriver                        0x0000000100468fa0 chromedriver + 315296
E       4   chromedriver                        0x000000010046aad8 chromedriver + 322264
E       5   chromedriver                        0x000000010046ac04 chromedriver + 322564
E       6   chromedriver                        0x00000001004a880c chromedriver + 575500
E       7   chromedriver                        0x00000001004a68e4 chromedriver + 567524
E       8   chromedriver                        0x00000001004a4844 chromedriver + 559172
E       9   chromedriver                        0x00000001004a3930 chromedriver + 555312
E       10  chromedriver                        0x0000000100497f90 chromedriver + 507792
E       11  chromedriver                        0x0000000100497858 chromedriver + 505944
E       12  chromedriver                        0x00000001004dad28 chromedriver + 781608
E       13  chromedriver                        0x0000000100496178 chromedriver + 500088
E       14  chromedriver                        0x0000000100496fc0 chromedriver + 503744
E       15  chromedriver                        0x00000001007fac40 chromedriver + 4058176
E       16  chromedriver                        0x00000001007ff160 chromedriver + 4075872
E       17  chromedriver                        0x00000001007c2e68 chromedriver + 3829352
E       18  chromedriver                        0x00000001007ffc4c chromedriver + 4078668
E       19  chromedriver                        0x00000001007d7f08 chromedriver + 3915528
E       20  chromedriver                        0x000000010081c140 chromedriver + 4194624
E       21  chromedriver                        0x000000010081c2c4 chromedriver + 4195012
E       22  chromedriver                        0x000000010082c4d0 chromedriver + 4261072
E       23  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000184123fa8 _pthread_start + 148
E       24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018411eda0 thread_start + 8

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:245: StaleElementReferenceException
```

So as it seems to me the loop is exited before any exceptions are thrown.

Intended behavior should be :

1. Function called
2. Wait triggered.
3. StaleElementReferenceException.
4. Stale element occured. Retrying after {find_element_wait_timeout} seconds for {find_element_retries} times.
5. Loop trying to get the element multiple times
6. It gets the element

Major aspect of the issue is also that these StaleElementReferenceException are highly unstable. Meaning there is no way to know if the test will get it or not. Approximately I get 5 out of 100 tests.

Comment: Where does the "FAILED" come from?  That's happening before the function is called.  Maybe it's already in a bad state.  Catching this kind of error is tricky, because the exception is actually happening in the helper thread that Selenium launched to perform your wait.

Comment: I am using pytest to run the tests, it produces either "PASSED" or "FAILED" output, determining if test passes or failed.

Comment: Removing WebDriverWait has done the trick for me! Thank you!